# QuizUp alternative for Android?

Tags: android, game

Is there any application similar to [QuizUp](https://www.quizup.com/) for Android, that would contain questions in English?

QuizUp is a millionaire-like application, where the user is presented with a series of questions with 4 possible answers, from which only 1 is correct. Simultaneously, another user is answering the same questions, and after all, the winner is chosen.

There's [QuizDuell](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.feomedia.quizkampen.de.lite), but it's in German... I'd like to be able to play in English language.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example, not everybody knows *QuizUp*; so you'd better include what features you need, and which you'd optionally like, plus whether you've got a price limit. Oh, and don't forget to mention the minimum Android version it should run on :)

Comment: Some suggestions on additional criteria - would you want custom questions or stock ones, and in what sort of fields?

Comment: I don't want to be so picky. Finding something matching the above criteria may be already difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quizup now has an [official Android port](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quizup.core)

Features

- Is actually quizup, so it should have all the features you want.
- It's an app that has a large question bank, topics, and asks you multiple choice questions.

Apparently it will crash horribly if you're running the ART runtime (if you have to ask what it is, you don't have to worry - its an alternative to dalvik on some android 4.4 devices), but it's in English, and should have the same features as the iOS version.

Comment: FYI: [QuizUp now supports ART](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quizup.core).